# Selenium: Browser stays open even though it should close

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber, bdd

```
public class MS848Steps {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Given("Website is live and available")
    public void website_is_live_and_available() {
        System.out.println("Website is live and available!");
    }

    @When("Website works on Firefox")
    public void website_works_on_firefox() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://demowebshop.tricentis.com/");
        System.out.println("Website works on Firefox!");
    }

    @And("Website works on Chrome")
    public void website_works_on_chrome() {

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://demowebshop.tricentis.com/");
        System.out.println("Website works on Chrome!");
    }

    @And("Website works on Edge")
    public void website_works_on_edge() {
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.get("https://demowebshop.tricentis.com/");
        System.out.println("Website works on Edge!");
    }

    @Then("Website works on every browser")
    public void website_works_on_every_browser() {
        System.out.println("Website works on every Browsers!");
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

If i execute the following Code, the Chrome and Firefox Browser remains open. I also tried to put a driver.close(); and driver.quit(); after each Browser is opened. But nothing helped. Even ChatGBT couldnt help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use the same variable name for all three methods. The last time you declare the driver variable will be the one that quits. You should name the driver for each browser separately such as "chomreDriver" and then quit all of them.